# Creating coordinate from a list of doubles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a form in spring boot in which people can create 1 or more coordinates.
The input fields are seperated (for the X and Y) but have all the same name, so all the coordinates that people create are put inside a list of doubles. Now I am having the problem that I need to convert it to a list of coordinates instead. The values in the list are all correctly ordered (index 0 is the X and index 1 is the Y coordinate and starting with index 2 a new coordinate starts etc). But I am not sure how to get every time 2 list values from a stream to create a coordinate. Here is the code I have untill now:

```
public class LocationForm {
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=6, max=64)
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private LocationType type;
    @ListNotBlank
    private List<Double> geometry;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public LocationType getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(LocationType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public List<Double> getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }
    public void setGeometry(List<Double> geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }
}
```

The above code validate the inputs from my form and makes a object from it. The input field for the coordinate look as follows:

```
<div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="coordinates">Coordinate X</label>
                          <input type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('geometry')} ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" name="geometry" id="geometry" 
                          placeholder="Enter coordinates" >
                          <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('geometry')}" th:errors="*{geometry}" class="text-danger"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="coordinates">Coordinate Y</label>
                          <div class="d-flex">
                              <input type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('geometry')} ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" name="geometry" id="geometry" 
                              placeholder="Enter coordinates" >
                              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="geometry_fields();">Add</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Above you can see that both the X and Y are seperate, but since they have the same name all of them will be put in the list of doubles. Does someone know how to make a list of coordinates with the above input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues. Firstly, update your model to something like `List<Coordinate>` where `Coordinate` is a simple bean with 2 props `x` and `y`.

Secondly, to bind to a List in Spring MVC you need to use indexed properties. So your form will be like:

```
<input type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('geometry')} ? 
             'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" name="coordinate[0].x">

<input type="text" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('geometry')} ? 
              'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" name="coordinate[0].y">
```

then `coordinate[1].x` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Since your (business) model is representing 2 co-ordinate system why create `List<Double>`. Instead, try to solve it by changing your `geometry` object to 2 different objects say, `Double X; Double Y;`

This will make the data flow between view-model-controller pain-free.

If you are planning to do lots of geospacial stuff then have a look at using this [Apache SIS](https://sis.apache.org/)

Comment: As you maybe can see you can add more of such input fields so creating multipele X and Y coordinates. With this you would still have to create a coordinate then from 2 double lists

Comment: so one location form for collecting multiple co-ordinate fields??

Comment: You can create coordinates which will form or a point (in which case it is just one coordinate) but you can also create polygons which is ofcourse build up from multipele coordinates

Comment: Yes. if your use case is to support multiple coordinates then Alan's approach should work right?